# Permanent login in mvc.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-security

I am working on permanent login in MVC.net application, i have tried using IsPersistent = true in FormAuthantication, but if i restart iis then it logs out the uses
below is the code which is responsible for loging in.

```
public void SetLoginData(UserLoginInfo userLoginInfo)
        {
            HttpContext .Current.Session[SessionUserEmailIdKey] = userLoginInfo.Email;
            HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionWelcomeNameKey] = userLoginInfo.FirstName;
            HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionWelcomeRegistrationIdKey] = userLoginInfo.RegistrationId;

            HttpContext.Current.Session[SessionLoginInfoKey] = userLoginInfo;
            const bool isPersistent = true;
            const string userData = "user";

            var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                                                       userLoginInfo.RegistrationId.ToString(
                                                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                                                       DateTime.UtcNow,
                                                       DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(180),
                                                       isPersistent,
                                                       userData,
                                                       FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
        }
```

please tell me how can i implement login so that even though app restarts, users will not e logged out.

Comment: Hey, can you send me and example for `GetLoginData` please. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create perpetual logins, you will need to make sure two things are in place (since you are using FormsAuthentication).

First - ensure your ticket expiration time is set to sometime way out in the future

```
 = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        userLoginInfo.RegistrationId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        DateTime.UtcNow,
        DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(20),
        isPersistent,
        userData,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
```

Second (and most likely why users are getting kicked out of the site when you reboot IIS) is to create a machineKey section in your web.config with a static key pair set.  By default, IIS autogenerates a machineKey per app.  This is what is used to encrypt/decrypt your forms authentication tickets.  If IIS restarts, you will most likely get a new machine key in this instance, which means that the ticket cannot be decrypted.... meaning user has to log in again.  By creating/defining a static key, you can prevent a key change when IIS recycles.  Information on setting the machine key can be [found on MSDN here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772287%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

Lastly, forms authentication has *ZERO* to do with sessions and session management.  They are mutually exclusive and do not impact each other in typical scenarios.  When a user logs in, they are given an encrypted cookie containing the expiration time and user name.  This is *NOT* stored in session, so adjusting session settings will have no impact on user logins.